# What blockchain security and decentralization metrics exist?

Tags: blockchain, security, decentralization

I want to quantify decentralization and the chain security. What metrcis exists besdies the the Nakomoto coefficient?

I want to have a mesurement how decentralised and how secure the chain is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other metrics such as Lorenz curve, Gini coefficient, Herfindahl-Hirschman index, and Theil L/T index.

See: https://www.smartcontractresearch.org/t/notable-works-in-decentralization-metrics/828